# Updating neo4j from 2.1.1 to 2.1.6 losing spatial data

Tags: neo4j, upgrade, spatial

I'm trying to upgrade my database neo4j from 2.1.1 to 2.1.6. 
It has spatial indexes inside and I configured the neo4j.properties to set

```
allow_store_upgrade=true
```

But even with that configuration, when I run neo4j, my database's weight goes from 88Mb to 14Mb. All the nodes are there, but when I run a spatial query I get

```
Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure
```

Is there anything I can do about it?

**EDIT**

Apparently the lose of weight is because neo4j wipes out all the log files, not losing data. Is seems to be a spatial error in v2.1.6 with my current DB from v2.1.1 (Using spatial plugin v2.1.2)

If I replace `neo4j-spatial-0.13-neo4j-2.1.6.jar` with `neo4j-spatial-0.13-neo4j-2.1.2.jar` it works, which is a bit weird because it looks like v2.1.6 cannot read the information stored by v2.1.2

**EDIT 2**

The query I'm running is:

```
START n=node:LocationIndex('withinDistance:[51.0,-0.12,10.0]') RETURN n;
```

where LocationIndex is my spatial index.

The DB structure contains nodes with wkt, lon and lat like this:

```
wkt: POINT(-0.142309 51.538400)
lon: -0.122309
lat: 51.5384
```

When I add the old plugin it returns all the nodes, with the old one it returns the error above.

What can be the error and how can I upgrade my spatial information?

Comment: Any useful info in the logs (`data/graph.db/messages.log`)?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Apparently the decrease of weight is because it deletes all the logs: "Non clean shutdown detected on log". Still don't know why spatial fails if the index is Online

Comment: @StefanArmbruster where can I see the log of the error in order to get some more details about it?

Comment: I've changed the spatial jar v2.1.6 for my current spatial jar v2.1.2 and it works, even in 2.1.6... Does that mean the spatial content from my DB can only be used by that version of the plugin??

Comment: It would be good to see the actual 'spatial query' being run, as well as (if possible) a sample of the database structure, so we could try reproduce this issue.

Comment: Sure @CraigTaverner!, I'll add this to the original post, but I was trying to run the simplest withinDistance query in the simplest database :)